# autogenerate method comments for java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

How do I auto generate method comments for java code in eclipse.  Basically what I want is as below

```
/**
 * @param  ${param_name}  ${param_type} 
 * @return ${return type}
 */
```

I did looked at other threads but I didn't get the clue for doing the above for methods. 
I got that for class though.

Comment: Such a comment would be completely useless, and would only add noise. The name of the parameters, their type, and the type of the returned value is already in the method signature, which is displayed by the javadoc.

Comment: +1 for the above comment.  It you can autogenerate it I would suggest it's adding no value whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want the "Add Javadoc Comment" command?
Default shortcut is Alt-Shift+J

Answer (score 0):

Install `JAutodoc` plugin from [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jautodoc#.UwrrBx9sM38). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

More info [here](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/)